# Trouble creating/using snort rules in terminal (OS: VM Mint 17)

Tags: tcp, alert, rules, linux-mint, snort

I am using snort 2.9.6 and am having trouble getting my rules to run. When I run snort I receive the following error

Initializing rule chains...
ERROR: /etc/snort/rules/(1) Unknown rule type alert
Fatal Error, Quitting..

I have tried copying/using multiple rules from other rules files,etc.. so that they would have the correct syntax, yet none of them seem to be working

Here's an example of a rule I am trying just as a catch all over tcp in order to verify that the rules are being executed

Example: alert tcp any any -> 172.16.136.129 any (msg:"any, any"; sid:1000011;)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Thanks for your help